# Buoyancy force in fluid dyanamics

Tags: buoyancy

How to calculate the force of buoyancy on a body which is placed at the bottom of the liquid container?

Comment: Archimedes' Principle applies whether the body is partially or fully submerged.

Answer (score 1):

The buoyancy force acting on a body is the total force due to pressure difference across its vertical height. Consider the image,

[image]

The buoyancy force on the body is

$$F_B=\int_A P(h)~~dA $$
The pressure variation with height is

$$P(h)=\rho g h + Pa$$
where $Pa$ is the atmospheric pressure. Performing the integration over the entire body gives the net buoyant force. This integration can be easily performed for standard bodies like cubes, cylinders, spheres etc.

From the expression of $P(h)$ we see that the pressure difference in horizontal direction is cancelled out and only the pressure difference across the vertical direction adds up to the total force.

If both the body and the cylinder are flat bottomed (as I gather from your question) and the bottom faces are in contact, then the pressure force acting on the bottom face of the body is zero (Since no fluid in contact). Only the pressure force on the top face contributes to the buoyant force.

If the study is about whether the body floats/sinks in a fluid, then take into account the weight of the body (or density distribution of the body) acting downwards due to gravity.

Hope I have answered your question!

Note: All the datum reference is with respect to the gravity. (Vertical is the direction downwards along which gravity acts; horizontal is normal to line of action of gravity)